# The mathematical problem with beer

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

A problem is given:

*$322$ mathematicians walk into a bar, numbered from $1$ to $322$, each picks someone other than himself at random and writes down his number on a piece of paper. The barman names the first mathematician, he orders a beer for the one he has written on the slip, then the next mathematician in line comes to the barman who has not yet been ordered a beer, orders the one he has written on the slip and so on. How many mathematicians will be left without beer in the expectation?*

My attempt at a solution:

Let's denote by $X_i$ a random variable that equals 1 if the $i$th mathematician did not get a beer, and equals 0 if the $i$th mathematician got a beer. We want to find the mathematical expectation of the number of mathematicians who will remain without beer
$$\mathbb{E}\left [ \sum_{i=1}^{322}X_i \right ]=\sum_{i=1}^{322}\mathbb{E}[X_i]$$
Now we need to find the mathematical expectation of $X_i$. Consider the $i$th mathematician. The chance that he won't get a beer is equal to the probability that his name won't be written on a piece of paper by someone else. The probability that $i$th mathematician will not be chosen by $j$th mathematician is $\frac{321}{321}$ (since $j$ cannot choose himself). The probability that $i$-th mathematician will not be chosen by any of the other $321$-mathematicians is equal to:
$$\left ( 1-\frac{1}{321} \right )^{321}$$
We can now find the mathematical expectation of $X_i$:
$$\mathbb{E}[X_i]=1\cdot \left ( 1-\frac{1}{321} \right )^{321}+0\cdot \left ( 1-\left ( 1-\frac{1}{321} \right )^{321} \right )\approx 0,368$$
On average about $0,368 \cdot 322 \approx 118,6$ of maths will be left without beer. The answer is $\boxed{119}$

**I'm not at all sure about the decision. Could you tell me if I have solved it correctly ?**

Comment: Looks correct to me. As a side note $\mathbb E[X_i]$ is very close to $1/e$.

Comment: So it's all right? Thanks for the comment!

Comment: "The chance that he won't get a beer is equal to the probability that his name won't be written on a piece of paper by someone else". I'm not sure. What if his name was written only by the mathematician got the first beer?

Comment: "The first mathematician" is chosen at random, or is mathetician number one? (same for the next choosings=

Comment: Also wrong (obviously) is the fraction $\frac{321}{321}$

Comment: The process is not totally clear : you forgot this part of the message : ' then the next mathematician in line comes to the barman who has not yet been ordered a beer,"  So we will not read all the papers, we read a paper only if this mathematician did not already  drink a beer. I think that Stas Volkov has a better understanding of the question.

Comment: If the process is : read all the papers, and give a beer to all numbers on papers, it was not useful to say that we read paper n°1 , then n°2 .. etc

Answer (score 1):

I presume that when the $k-1$-th mathematician is called for beer, and the number which she has written is in the set of the first $(k-2)$ mathematicians, the process stops. Assuming each chooses a number at random uniformly and independently from the set of $(N-1)$ possible ones (where $N=322$), the conditional probability that $k$-th will be not the last one (given she has been chosen), is $1-\frac{k-2}{N-1}$. Hence if $X$ denotes the number of mathematicians who got bear, then
$$
\mathbb{P}(X\ge k)=\left(1-\frac1{N-1}\right)\left(1-\frac2{N-1}\right)...\left(1-\frac{k-2}{N-1}\right)
=\frac{(N-2)(N-3)...(N-(k-1))}{(N-1)^{k-2}}
=\frac{(N-2)!}{(N-k)!\,(N-1)^{k-2}}
$$
for $k\ge 3$, and $\mathbb{P}(X\ge 1)=\mathbb{P}(X\ge 2)=1$.
Hence
$$
\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\mathbb{P}(X\ge k)=2+\sum_{k=3}^{N}\left(1-\frac1{N-1}\right)\left(1-\frac2{N-1}\right)...\left(1-\frac{k-2}{N-1}\right)=23.12737336.
$$